# Find index location of first and last occurrence of a value per day in a Pandas DataFrame with a DateTime index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the first and last occurrence of a value for each day in a column.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                       a        b        c
2019-04-01 19:47:00    False    False     True
2019-04-01 19:48:00    False    False     True
2019-04-01 19:49:00    True     False     True
2019-04-01 19:50:00    True     False     True
2019-04-01 19:51:00    True     False     True
...
2019-04-28 11:22:00    False    True      False
2019-04-28 11:23:00    False    True      False
2019-04-28 11:24:00    False    False     True
2019-04-28 11:25:00    False    False     False
2019-04-28 11:26:00    False    False     False
```

And I want to find the index of the first and last occurrence of True for each day (2019-04-01 through 2019-04-28), and append that to another DataFrame.

How do you recommend I go about that?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you made an attempt at solving this? What format do you want the output in? Is `True` valid in any of the `a`, `b` or `c` columns? Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['d'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime(date_format='%Y%m%d')
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ['date','a','b','c','d']
df[(sum([df['a'],df['b'],df['c']])>0)].groupby('d').agg(first=('date','first'),
                                                         last=('date','last'))
```

Output

```
                        first                 last
d
20190401  2019-04-01 19:47:00  2019-04-01 19:51:00
```